# API Call to few open Source APIs is not working even after setting proxy in Karate

Tags: api, rest, testing, karate

I am behind corporate proxy and using Karate to hit GET call to reqres API. Instead of 200, I am getting 403 error code. Please let me know if any other information is required.

- Java Version: 1.8
- Maven Version: 3.6.3

It seems that the issue is specific to few APIs. I tried multiple APIs and majority of the APIs are working except few APIs with the same error. Listing down the APIs:

**Not Working**

1. https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users
2. https://reqres.in/api/users/2

**Working**

1. http://www.7timer.info/bin/astro.php?lon=113.2&lat=23.1&ac=0&unit=metric&output=json&tzshift=0
2. https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1
3. https://fakerestapi.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/Activities
4. https://randomuser.me
5. https://httpbin.org/#/HTTP_Methods/get_get
6. https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json?brand=maybelline
7. http://numbersapi.com/random/math
8. http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

Please find my feature file:

```
Feature: Sample API Test
      Scenario: get user details with path parameter
          * configure proxy = 'http:myproxy:8080'
          * configure ssl = true;
          Given header Content-Type = 'application/json'
          And header Accept = 'application/json'
          When url 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2'
          When method GET
          Then status 200
          * print 'result: ',response
```

POM Dependency:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-junit4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Error Message:

```
    status code was: 403, expected: 200, response time in milliseconds: 464, url: https://reqres.in/api/users/2, response: 
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Could not connect to server</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://reqres.in/%24%24%24%26%3f%26%3f%24%24%24?cmd=get_file&arg=block_style.css&sid=90709ACBF52361FBE728AFA2A8AE02A868DB9E86" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div id="pagecontainer">
            <img class="icon" src="https://reqres.in/%24%24%24%26%3f%26%3f%24%24%24?cmd=get_file&arg=images/block.png&sid=7B320C491CF4319D6D2C8C17BA9FE6DA2ECA16B8"> <!--Icon for block type-->
            <h1>Could not connect to server</h1>
    
            <div class="row">
                    <p class="label">Overview:</p>
                    <p class="item">Could not connect to reqres.in </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <p class="label">Details:</p>
                    <p class="item">Peer suddenly disconnected</p>
            </div>
    
            <div id="options">
                    <p class="label">Options:</p>
                    <form action=""><input type="button" class="button" onclick="history.back();" value="   Go Back   "></form><p class="item">Click to return to the previous page:</p>
                    <p class="last-item">Make sure the URL is correct, then try to reload the page.</p>
            </div>
    
            <div><img class="logo" title="Forcepoint" src="https://reqres.in/%24%24%24%26%3f%26%3f%24%24%24?cmd=get_file&arg=images/wslogo_block_page.png&sid=46D63EFDD3551F01875504354D49CF431151A9BE" alt="Forcepoint Logo">
                    <div style="clear: both; overflow: hidden; height:1px;"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: just so you know, it is impossible (at least for me) to help you if I can't replicate the problem. you can search other answers in case you get some hints. or maybe work with your local IT support. all the best: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+proxy

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas for the reply. I tried to hit the same APIs using Rest Assured (Java) after setting the proxy and it is working fine. So, it seems that there is something missing at Karate API end. Also, I used the latest version of karate and removed all the previous versions as after 1.0 upgrade, user has to use only 1 API as mentioned in https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide. I can provide the Rest Assured code if required

Comment: I'm sorry, you'll have to provide proof that there is "something missing". to put this another way, if I can't experience the problem, I can't fix it. I'm sure you understand. so if you can follow this process (exactly as described) please do so, or maybe you have to stick with rest-assured. I'm sorry I have no better suggestions, but maybe someone else can comment. all the best ! https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to set the proxy that Karate uses. Please refer to the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configure

Also see other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+http+proxy